# Is there a way to force a user session timeout in Websphere?

Tags: session, timeout, websphere, commerce

I need to do some testing to the session timeout logic and how timeouts are handled, but I don't want to have to wait for the session to time out.  Right now it takes 30 minutes of inactivity to time out, is there a way to either change this to a much lower timeframe or, even better, force the timeout whenever I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invalidate the HTTP Session, which is very similar to what occurs during a timeout, by calling HTTPSession#invalidate.  You could do this trivially with a JSP.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null) { 
    session.invalidate();
}
```

You can also adjust the timeouts at the application level in the WAS console:

```
All Applications > $yourapp > Session management
```

Comment: I don't see any instances of a "request" object in any of the java files, even though it really feels like it SHOULD already exist somewhere.  Is there a particular way I have to create this object?

Comment: Well in a JSP there's implicitly a "request" that is an HTTPServletRequest.  Otherwise e.g. in a servlet, your entry point usually has an HTTPServletRequest or ServletRequest parameter (e.g. public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse rsp))

Comment: otherwise if your app actually makes use of the http session, you should have references to the session already.